# What is the intuitive meaning behind Coulomb's constant $k_e$?

Tags: coulombs-law

What is the intuitive meaning behind [Coulomb's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_constant) $k_e$?
If the force of an electric field can be calculated by

$$F=k_eqQ/d^2$$

If I could guess I would say $k_e$ is the acceleration but I am not sure.

Comment: Does *it is a constant of proportionality* suffice? Because that's really all it is.

Answer (score 2):

Its the force experience by two unit charges by each other when separated by a distance of 1 metre.

Comment: That is correct but OP is looking for an intuitive meaning of it. On the other hand I think your answer is as intuitive as it gets

Comment: @gonenc So you are confused?

Answer (score 0):

Coulomb's constant has units of metres per Farad. It is not acceleration; it is oftern expressed in terms of the vacuum permitivity for a free vacuum $k_\text{e} = \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}$.